# How to improve slow PXE boot

Tags: virtualbox, pxe

I am in the process of getting parts together for my new PC. I currently have Virtualbox hosting a Win 2k8 and Windows 7 and each have 2 processors and 2 gigs of ram but PXE booting takes 2-3 minutes. My host machine has a core 2 quad q6600 and 8 gigs of ram. The same boot image takes 30 seconds to load on a machine at work. So my question is, with a newer computer does faster pxe booting come? Or is there one particular piece of hardware I want to make sure is maxed. I plan on getting the fastest core i5 and 16 gigs of ram, a solid state drive and 2 1tb raid drives for my data.

Answer (score 1):

i have had device drivers that performed at 10Mbps with 1/2 duplex during the PXE boot and once the OS was completely up.  1/2 duplex will makes ACKs especially slow like Pat mentioned above.  To make it more complex to troubleshoot, there can be multiple drivers involved.

During a complete PXE boot, there can be 3 separate "drivers".
  1.) The initial raw network card PXE speed.
  2.) Once an image is chosen, the PXE bootup NIC speed.
  3.) Once the complete Operating System is loaded, the normal OS driver.